# Оценка сложности алгоритма Евклида (НОД)

Tags: алгоритм

Изучаю книгу "Алгоритмы" Рода Стивенса. В самом начале представляется классический алгоритм Евклида для нахождения НОД. Всё просто и понятно:

```
НОД(А, В) = НОД(В, А mod В)
```

Как итог - автор приводит асимптотическую сложность алгоритма, которая равна O(log(B)). И я никак не могу понять, почему это так. В самом начале автор объяснял сложность O(log(N)) на примере поиска элемента бинарного сбалансированного полного дерева. Почему у него такая сложность - я понял. А вот с НОД - никак не пойму. Разъясните пожалуйста. Спасибо.

P.S.: я относительный новичок в оценке сложности алгоритмов, поэтому буду рад очень подробному объяснению.

Comment: [Вот не самая плохая лекция на эту тему...](http://www.uni.bsu.by/arrangements/seminar_t4/lekcii/lecture_1.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `B` увеличить в `B` раз, количество операций (в плохом случае) увеличится в два раза.